# Automating system configuration with Git

Tags: git, github

I am trying to automate a system configuration so that, when a new machine is run, I can set up my development environment without having to download everything manually or add things to the path. Is it possible to use Git or GitHub to automate a system configuration? If you have shell scripts and other files that help set up the development environment on Git, could they be pulled off and implemented? My goal here is to be able to setup the environment with Java, Python, MongoDB, and more without having to go to the sites and manually download them every time.

Comment: what do you want to automate? setting up of development environment with sdk like java, python and then download configurations for your project from somewhere and you start coding?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that I can create a new VM, then configure all of the development tools and be ready to code the existing project as well as any future projects without having to setup the environment manually.

Comment: You should check [docker](https://www.docker.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called *configuration management*, and you can certainly use git as *part of* a configuration management solution.

In the simplest case, you would have a library of shell scripts and configuration files stored in a remote git repository that you would clone onto the new system, and in that repository some master shell script that would perform all the necessary tasks in the correct order.

You may, however, want to investigate some the tools designed explicitly to help automate the process of configuration management.  A popular choice these days is [Ansible](http://ansible.com), which has a relatively simple syntax and is reasonably easy to get started with.

Other solutions include [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com) and [Chef](https://www.chef.io/), although I think both are probably more complicated to work with.

Vishwanath mentions [Docker](http://docker.com) in the comments, which provides a different solution to the problem: rather than installing a variety of tools onto your host, you would instead preconfigure Docker images and start your tools in containers in the host.  There are advantages to this model as well, although getting a successful container-based solution will probably require more time to get right if this is your first exposure to container technology.